# Keeping enums in separate script files

Tags: c#, enums

I have been keeping my enums in separate scripts instead like this...

```
public enum PrefabID { Pistol, SubmachineGun, HMG, }
```

Instead of doing this...

```
public class Shooter
{
  public enum PrefabID { Pistol, SubmachineGun, HMG, }    
}
```

does this have any compile time penalties **(increase the compile time)** or it does **increase the built executable size**?

I'm using C#

Comment: or compile time

Comment: @eocron in the voyage of making your exe tiny by using c/c++, you have now increased compile times to the ridiculous

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the compile times remains the same whether there are more script files for the enums or there are enums inside another class script. Both this...

```
public enum PrefabID { Pistol, SubmachineGun, HMG, }
```

and this...

```
public class Shooter
{
  public enum PrefabID { Pistol, SubmachineGun, HMG, }    
}
```

doesn't harm the compile time in any way, But the size is definitely affected as the **the first style increases the built executable size by a few bytes but the second style doesn't**.

Comment: This is very helpfull.

Comment: _"...the first style increases the built executable size by a few bytes..."_ - 1) are compiling in **Release**?  2) a few bytes is insignificant and unless your app consists of mostly `enum`s (that would be weird) it's not a realistic problem.   3) a few bytes won't matter because a 1 byte "file" and a 512 byte "file" are still going to consume the same disk cluster size (typically 4KB) on NTFS.  Anyway, +1

Comment: oh, really? thanks again for the input sir. didn't know that.